# Showing values for overall dataset as well as subset

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset that contains various wait-time metrics for all appointments in a practice for a year (check-in to call-back, call-back to check-out, etc).  It contains appt time (one of about 40 15 minute slots), provider, various wait times.

I can get Tableau to show me, for each 15 minute slot, the average wait times for each provider in the practice.

What I can't seem to be able to do is also display the overall average for the practice for that given time slot so as to be able to compare that provider vs. the "office standard".

I'm super new to trying out Tableau, so I am sure it is something very simple.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a level-of-detail (LOD) calculated field. An LOD calculation occurs at whatever aggregation level you specify, rather than what's on the row or column shelf.

You didn't provide any info about your data set so I will use made up names here.

This gives you the overall average wait time, regardless of other dimensions on row/column shelves:

```
{FIXED : avg([wait time])}
```

This gives you the overall average wait time per provider, regardless of other dimensions on row/column shelves:

```
{FIXED [Provider Name] : avg([wait time])}
```

See the online Tableau help at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html for more information. If you have filtering and need to calculate the overall without filters applied, look at the `INCLUDE` LOD keyword.

Comment: For the overall average, you can even avoid typing 6 characters by using {avg([wait time])}. The FIXED keyword is implied in that case.

Comment: Cool @AlexBlakemore. I had no idea that FIXED was implied. Thanks for sharing that.